# How to use Gcc 4.6.0 libquadmath and __float128 on x86 and x86_64

Tags: gcc, floating-point, precision, 128-bit

I have medium size C99 program which uses `long double` type (80bit) for floating-point computation. I want to improve precision with new GCC 4.6 extension `__float128`. As I get, it is a software-emulated 128-bit precision math.

How should I convert my program from classic long double of 80-bit to quad floats of 128 bit with software emulation of full precision?
What need I change? Compiler flags, sources?

My program have reading of full precision values with `strtod`, doing a lot of different operations on them (like +-*/ sin, cos, exp and other from `<math.h>`) and `printf`-ing of them.

PS: despite that float128 is declared only for Fortran (REAL*16), the libquadmath is written in C and it uses float128. I'm unsure will GCC convert operations on float128 to runtime library or not and I'm unsure how to migrate from long double to __float128 in my sources.

PPS: There is a documentation on "C" language gcc mode: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Floating-Types.html

> "GNU C compiler supports ... 128 bit (TFmode) floating types. Support for additional types includes the arithmetic operators: **add, subtract, multiply, divide**; unary arithmetic operators; relational operators; equality operators ...  __float128 types are supported on i386, x86_64"

Comment: libquadmath is here http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libquadmath/index.html#toc_Top and here is news about this http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html "GCC now ships with the LGPL-licensed libquadmath library, which provides quad-precision mathematical functions for targets with a __float128 datatype. __float128 is available for targets on 32-bit x86, x86-64 and Itanium architectures. "

Comment: turn that basic operations are done by `glibc/soft-fp`, e.g `__subtf3()` http://koala.cs.pub.ro/lxr/#glibc+2.9/soft-fp/subtf3.c#L35  http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Software_floating_point

Comment: using libquadmath, you can use [strtoflt128](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:P0PwG_dRv4EJ:gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libquadmath.ps.gz+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=ubuntu) as a `strtod` replacement.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> How should I convert my program from classic long double of 80-bit to quad floats of 128 bit with software emulation of full precision? What need I change? Compiler flags, sources?

You need recent software, GCC version with support of `__float128` type (4.6 and newer) and libquadmath (supported only on [x86 and x86_64 targets](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Floating-Types.html); in IA64 and HPPA with newer GCC). You should add linker flag `-lquadmath` (the `cannot find -lquadmath'` will show that you have no libquadmath installed)

- Add `#include <quadmath.h>` header to have macro and function definitions.
- You should modify all `long double` variable definitions to `__float128`.
- Complex variables may be changed to `__complex128` type (`quadmath.h`) or directly with `typedef _Complex float __attribute__((mode(TC))) _Complex128;`
- All simple arithmetic operations are automatically handled by GCC (converted to calls of helper functions like `__*tf3()`).
- If you use any macro like `LDBL_*`, replace them with `FLT128_*` (full list http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libquadmath/Typedef-and-constants.html#Typedef-and-constants)
- If you need some specific constants like pi (`M_PI`) or e (`M_E`) with quadruple precision, use predefined constants with `q` suffix (`M_*q`), like `M_PIq` and `M_Eq` (full list http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libquadmath/Typedef-and-constants.html#Typedef-and-constants)
- User-defined constants may be written with `Q` suffix, like `1.3000011111111Q`
- All math function calls should be replaced with `*q` versions, like `sqrtq()`, `sinq()` (full list http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libquadmath/Math-Library-Routines.html#Math-Library-Routines)
- Reading quad-float from string should be done with `__float128 strtoflt128 (const char *s, char **sp)` - http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libquadmath/strtoflt128.html#strtoflt128 (Warning, in older libquadmaths there may be some bugs in strtoflt128, do a double check)
- Printing the `__float128` is done with help of `quadmath_snprintf` function. On linux distributions with recent glibc the function will be automagically registered by libquadmath to handle `Q` (may be also `q`) length modifier of `a, A, e, E, f, F, g, G` conversion specifiers in all `printf`s/`sprintf`s, like it did `L` for long doubles. Example: `printf ("%Qe", 1.2Q)`, http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libquadmath/quadmath_005fsnprintf.html#quadmath_005fsnprintf

You should also know, that since 4.6 Gfortran will use `__float128` type for DOUBLE PRECISION, if the option `-fdefault-real-8` was given and there were no option `-fdefault-double-8`. This may be problem, since 128 long double is much slower than standard long double on many platforms due to software computation. (Thanks to post by glennglockwood http://glennklockwood.blogspot.com/2014/02/linux-perf-libquadmath-and-gfortrans.html)