# C99: cast double to struct?

Tags: c, casting, refactoring

In the huge (millons of LOC) C project I want to expand a "double" type into a struct containing two doubles:

Now I have

```
typedef double popular_type;
//... a lot (>1k) usage of the type in expressions like:
popular_type a;
a = (popular_type) some_double_variable;
```

I want to change popular_type definition into

```
#ifdef SYNTHETIC_POPULAR_TYPE
typedef struct {
  double orig_field;
  double additional_field;
} popular_type;
#else
typedef double popular_type;
#endif
```

If I do not change the expressions like

```
popular_type a;
a = (popular_type) some_double_variable;
```

to

```
popular_type a;
a.orig_field = some_double_variable;
```

will the program work?

How can I redeclare `popular_type` in order that I do not have to change all assignments?

Comment: This projectis in C, with usage of some C99 features and 2-3 gcc extensions (supported by some other compilers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible.

If you change `popular_type` definition to

```
typedef struct {
  double orig_fiels;
  double additional_field;
} popular_type;
```

without changing assignments, the compiler will throw the error `conversion to non-scalar type requested`, so your code won't even compile, and there is no workaround over this. The only superior scalar type above `double` is `__float128`, and you can't just use the extra bytes to store your fields.

You really **have to change the assignments**, unfortunately.

Comment: The needed capability of editor is not regexp, but a real C parsing and type finding.

Comment: You may get errors when you make the change because the C compiler won't normally complain about the automatic conversion if someone uses a double instead of the old popular_type. You may start getting compiler errors all over the place where people didn't do the cast properly. Good luck.

Comment: The easier solution is to rewrite to "`a = (popular_type){some_double_variable,};`"

Comment: Cicada, can you look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457385/how-to-use-gcc-4-6-0-libquadmath-and-float128-on-x86-and-x86-64 ?

Comment: @Cicada: `__float128` is not standard.  `long double` is at least as big as `double`, but on some implementations it may be the same size.

Comment: @osgx: That's a compound literal, a new feature in C99 that might not be supported by all compilers.

Comment: I can use c99. My major compiler is gcc, and I can shift even to new versions, like 4.5.3

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to change the code -- but first, you'll need to decided exactly what you want the code to do.

The result of converting a `double` to the version of `popular_type` that's typedef'ed as a `double` is well defined.  After all, they're really the same type.  But what is the result of converting a `double` to a structure?  Given a `double` with the value 1.25, what should be the values of `orig_field` and `additional_field` in the resulting structure?

Once you've decided on the semantics, you can write a function (possibly inline) or perhaps a macro that does the conversion for you.  You'll still need to change each conversion so it calls your new function or macro (and possibly some assignments without casts, since with the current definition a cast is not required, as @Sam Hoice points out).  Fortunately, the compiler will tell you where this needs to be done.