# /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: undefined reference to `__strtof128_nan@GLIBC_PRIVATE'

Tags: makefile, undefined, ros, glibc

I use catkin_make to compile a ros project, but it failed.
it shows that there are some problems when linking the library.

```
[ 98%] Linking CXX executable /home/kyxz2021/fleet/devel/lib/data_parser/data_parser_node
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: undefined reference to `__strtof128_nan@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

i searched the error, someone said it might due to the inconsistency between libm version and libc version, but it is not the knot here.

```
***@ubuntu:~$ ll /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 May 16 20:52 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 -> libm-2.23.so
***@ubuntu:~$ ll /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1868984 Jun  5  2020 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      14 Feb 11  2016 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2 -> libcap.so.2.24
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   23128 Oct 23  2015 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2.24
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      21 Feb 11  2016 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcgmanager.so.0 -> libcgmanager.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  141248 Jan 18  2016 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcgmanager.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  190856 Jun  5  2020 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcidn-2.23.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 Jun  5  2020 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcidn.so.1 -> libcidn-2.23.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 Jan 22  2020 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 -> libcom_err.so.2.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14648 Jan 22  2020 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   39224 Jun  5  2020 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2366112 Feb 17 10:21 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      22 Feb 11  2016 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcryptsetup.so.4 -> libcryptsetup.so.4.6.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  158920 Sep  6  2017 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcryptsetup.so.4.6.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Jun  5  2020 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 -> libcrypt-2.23.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      12 Jun  5  2020 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.23.so*
```

And the output of nm -AD /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib{c,m}-2.23.so | grep __strtof128_nan is shown below.

```
***@ubuntu:~$ nm -AD /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib{c,m}-2.23.so | grep __strtof128_nan
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so:                 U __strtof128_nan
```

i don't know how to solve the problem, i'd be appreciated if someone could help me.

Comment: Please don't show _images_ of text. Cut/paste text into your question directly instead.

Comment: The definition of `__strtof128_nan@GLIBC_PRIVATE` should be in `libc-2.23.so`. Please edit your question and add the output from `nm -AD /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib{c,m}-2.23.so | grep __strtof128_nan` ?

Answer (score -1):

This particular error seems to be from not having float128 support (aka quadmath). [Check that your gcc version and libraries are new enough and have the right links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22870671). Since it's not a compile but linking error, perhaps you need to link against `-lquadmath`. But also, since your error msg seems to show the compilation target as custom code, do you need to be using quadmath?